# How to get var value from a text file?

Tags: javascript, file, text, input, var

For example, there is a http://test.com/a.txt file.

```
['http://a.com', false],
['http://b.com', false],
['http://c.com', false],
['http://d', false]
```

I want to use this file as a var value like below:

```
<script>
...
var list = [ ***I want to get that .txt file as values here.*** ];
...
</script>
```

**result**

```
<script>
...
var list = [ 
['http://a.com', false],
['http://b.com', false],
['http://c.com', false],
['http://d', false]
];
...
</script>
```

How can I make it?
I tried the javascript code below:

```
jQuery.get('http://test.com/a.txt', function(data) {
// The type o breaking line caracter will vary depending on OS
var values = data.split("\n");       
var List = values[values.length-1];              
});
```

But it didn't work...

Comment: It didn't work because you probably couldn't fetch the text file in the first place. Calling an external site from a browser is quite hard and often forbidden by cross-domain policy.

Comment: If the request is possible, possibly JSON.parse

Comment: you can if the request is allowed and you used JSONP. read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Does value give you something, or does the request fail ?

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie: The file's contents are not valid JSONP. Or JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this on a page with the same origin as that file (see the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)), or if that file's server supports [cross-origin requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) from your site, you could easily parse it as JSON by wrapping it in `[` and `]` and converting `'` to `"`:

```
jQuery.get('http://test.com/a.txt', function(data) {
    var list = JSON.parse("[" + data.replace(/'/g, '"') + "]");
    // ...
});
```

Naturally this assumes there are no `'` *inside* the `'`-quoted strings in the data.

If it's a cross-origin request that the server *doesn't* allow, you can't do it from a browser; you'd need to make the request to your own server and have your server request it from the other side.

---

Re your comment:

> I just tried it but it didn't work. It shows an error message. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in JSON at position 10233 at JSON.parse ()

Then the data isn't as you show in your question, because if it were, it would work:

```js
var data =
  "['http://a.com', false],\n" +
  "['http://b.com', false],\n" +
  "['http://c.com', false],\n" +
  "['http://d', false]";
console.log("data:");
console.log(data);
console.log("parsed:");
var list = JSON.parse("[" + data.replace(/'/g, '"') + "]");
console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work. It shows an error message.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in JSON at position 10233
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @Jenny: Then the data isn't as shown in your question; see proof in updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, because of [cross origin requests policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

However if the other url you gave was a link from a server, that allows cross origin requests, then `JQuery.get` would have work.

But since this is *very unlikely* to be a server you would get `Content-Type: text/plain` and not a JSON object. Which mean you then have to parse it as shown in other answer.

---

## hack

If you don't need the data to be synced with the server, is to download the file on your server using another scripting language, such as bash's `curl`. And then use this file to query with javascript:

```
# bash
curl 'http://test.com/a.txt' -o a.txt
```

```
jQuery.get('/a.txt', function(data) {
  /* use data here, may need to be parsed as in other answer */             
});
```

Comment: You can, if the server allows such cross domain calls... but it's unlikely.

Comment: Is it also impossible to call the entire variable like below?
http://test.com/a.txt
var list = [ 
['http://a.com', false],
['http://b.com', false],
['http://c.com', false],
['http://d', false]
];


and then,

<script>
...
** Can I call a .txt file here? **
...
</script>

Comment: what do you mean by _calling the entire variable_ ?

Comment: @Jenny I'm sorry I still don't get your question in comment. I've updated my answer though, is it enough ?